# Installing ember cli, Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid

Tags: visual-studio, ember.js, msbuild, ember-cli

I am attempting to install ember cli but run into the error

```
C:\Program Files  x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.
Win32.Targets(511,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed
or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.
[C:\Users\garrett\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\testem
\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client
\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
```

bufferutil is not existing in my library and gives this error when I attempt to install it

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp
.Win32.Targets(511,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not
installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected. 
[C:\Users\garrett\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
`failed with exit code: 1
```

it seems like its not targeting the correct version of visual studios but it does not specify a version

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Platform Toolset 110 is Visual Studio 2012.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Ff770576(v=VS.110).aspx

Install the correct .Net framework from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0x726c2(v=VS.110).aspx